# Need to run the following If Statements running in Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find a specific number in the given List which is in ascending Order. I have written all the if statements. But not sure how to run them in loop. 
Support to find a way how to run this in loop and whether number is available within the list.
For example :

```
list_of_number=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
number_to_identify=6
```

So need to output, whether 6 is under the list.
**But note that I'm aware that we can find this using the "FOR" Loop directly. I want to use following method to calculate**

Method need to follow : 
Find the middle element and compare with `number_to_identify`. Based on the decision (greater/lesser/equal) make a output and run this until find whether number is available within the list.

Here is coding I have written with "If Statement". But need to loop this If statement to find whether number is available within the given list.

```
list_of_number=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
number_to_identify=6

Start_Index=0
End_Index=len(list_of_number)
new_list=[]

middle_index=(End_Index-Start_Index)/2
middle_Element=list_of_number[int(middle_index)]
print(middle_index)
print(middle_Element)

if middle_Element<number_to_identify:
    Start_Index=middle_index
    new_list=list_of_number[int(Start_Index):int(End_Index)]
    print(new_list)
elif number_to_identify<middle_Element:
    End_Index=middle_index
    new_list=list_of_number[int(Start_Index):int(End_Index)]
    print(new_list)
else:
    if middle_Element==number_to_identify:
        print("Number is available within the list")
```

Comment: Are you trying out recursive binary search

Comment: Yes.. You are correct. Sort of that. But just want to output the new list and search from that repeatedly until find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a while loop and break if the number is found:

```
while True:
    middle_index = (end_index-start_index) / 2
    ...
    elif middle_element == number_to_identify:
        print("Number is in the list")
        break
```

BTW I respelled the variables to match [Python's recommended style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).

Answer (score 1):

```
def identify(num,lst):
    start = int((len(lst)/2) - ((len(lst)/2) % 1))
    while True:        
        if num > lst[start]:
            start += 1
        if num < lst[start]:
            start -= 1
        if num == lst[start]:
            print("Found number at index: {0}".format(start))
            return lst[start]

list_of_number=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
number_to_identify=6
identify(number_to_identify, list_of_number)
```

This will do the trick for you. If the length of your list is an even number, it will start at the first element right of the middle.

Comment: Thanks for the support. But my idea was take each half of the list and analyse the last element of half List.
For Example :
List1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
Number to check : 7

take the first half : [1,2,3,4].. "7" is greater than "4"(last element of this list. So 7 should be in other half. so take the second half for analysis.

temp_list=[5,6,7,8]
Take the first half [5,6]. Again "7" is higher than the last element of the temp list. So 7 can't be in this list also.

.......In this way need to check each half of the list and identify whehter 7 is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is bit bulky. But it will work. Please suggest if any modification required if we can make it more easy.

```
def find_number(list_number,num_to_check):
    Start_Index=0
    End_Index=len(list_number)-1
    new_list=list_number
    not_found=False

    while len(new_list)>2:
        middle_index=(End_Index-Start_Index)/2
        middle_Element=new_list[int(middle_index)]

        if new_list[0]==num_to_check or new_list[-1]==num_to_check:
            print("Number in List")
            break

    #If number is in Second Half of the list
        elif middle_Element<num_to_check:
            Start_Index=middle_index
            new_list=new_list[int(Start_Index):int(End_Index+1)]
            print(new_list)
            End_Index=len(new_list)
            Start_Index=0
            print(End_Index)
            not_found=False

    #If number is in First Half of the list
        elif num_to_check<middle_Element:
            End_Index=middle_index
            new_list=new_list[int(Start_Index):int(End_Index+1)]
            print(new_list)
            End_Index=len(new_list)
            print(End_Index)
            not_found=False

    #If Number is match with the middle number
        else:
            not_found=True
            break

    if not_found:
        print("Number in List")
    else:
        print("Number not in List")

l1 = [10,22,43,56,65,79,88,92,102]
n1 = 93
find_number(l1,n1)
```